Spring KafkaTemplate is setting some fields as blank after serialization
I have the following code snippet that should publish a message to kafka topic:
@SneakyThrows
public void publish(TransactionWebhookEvent event) {
    val payload = printer().includingDefaultValueFields().print(event);
    kafkaTemplate
            .send(topic, payload)
            .addCallback(result -> logPublishStatus(PUBLISHED, event), error -> logPublishStatus(FAILED, event));
}

The problem is that I verify some fields of type string that will be sent to kafka topic, they exist. But after publishing, and when checking kafka topic partition, these data are blank in some cases.
I'm using version 3.22.0 of protobuf for serialization. Spring boot version is 2.5.15. Spring kafka version is 2.7.14.
Any one ran into this problem before? I suspect it is something regarding serialization.

I guess this has nothing to do with Apache Kafka and Spring, too. Probably try to test that Protobuf serialization in the isolation.
